# Как создать конструктор структуры без параметров? С#

Tags: c#

Есть структура

```
public struct Unit {

    public int Value;
}
```

Хочу, чтобы при создании этой структуры значения присваивались в конструкторе:

```
public struct Unit {

    public int Value;

    public Unit () { // <== err, конструктор не может быть без параметров

         Value = 10;
    }

    public Unit (bool Bred) { // всё ок

         Value = 10;
    }
}
```

Приходиться делать так по глупому

```
public struct Unit {

    public int Value;

    public Unit Init() {

         Value = 10;
    }
}
```

Пустой конструктор есть возможность использовать?

Comment: ** Можно использовать class, а не struct, но тут данный выбор принципилен

Comment: в c# нельзя создать конструктор без параметров у струткуты, он автоматический создается и инициализирует все поля значениями по умолчанию

Answer (score 8):

То, что вы хотите, сделать нельзя. Постараюсь объяснить, почему.

Структуры — это такой способ оптимизации *классов*, удобный в некоторых сценариях. В каждом классе помимо всех полей, есть дополнительные служебные данные. Это 8 байт в 32-хбитных архитектурах и 16 байт в 64-хбитных.

Если вы объявите массив из 1000 объектов, такой массив будет занимать на 8000 или на 16000 байт больше, потому что с каждым объектом хранятся его служебные данные.

В структурах, в отличие от обычных классов, служебных данных нет, но за это приходится платить. Компилятор C# и среда CLR пытаются сделать вид, что структуры это обычные классы, но некоторых вещей мы не можем с ними сделать.

Например, нельзя сделать наследника структуры, хотя при работы мы как бы видим, что любая наша структура является наследницей `System.ValueType`, а тот в свою очередь является наследником `System.Object`. Эту *видимость* создаёт компилятор C#.

Точно также нельзя сделать в структуре конструктор по-умолчанию, который будет её инициализировать какими-то ненулевыми значениями.

Это сделано для того, чтобы ускорить инициализацию структур. Когда вы создаёте массив из структур на 1000 элементов, CLR просто выделяет ровно столько памяти, сколько нужно на хранение данных (никаких служебных заголовков) и обнуляет её. Обнуление — операция достаточно долгая, но процессор умеет такие вещи оптимизировать.

Если бы у вас был конструктор, который записывает что-то кроме нулей, то тогда CLR пришлось бы 1000 раз вызывать этот конструктор и он бы устанавливал свои значения. Это было бы гораздо дольше.
Так что структуры без конструктора всегда состоят только из нулевых байтов.
Детально об этом написано в книге Джеффри Рихтера CLR via C#, см. главы 5 и 6.

Вы можете имитировать инициализацию, определённым образом написав геттер свойства. Представим, у нас есть структура `Point` с полями `X` и `Y`, у которых значение по умолчанию равно 10. Мы можем описать внутренне поле типа `int?`, чтобы обрабатывать *особый случай*.

```
struct Point
{
    private int? x;
    private int? y;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x ?? 10; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y ?? 10; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}
```

Идея здесь в том, что nullable-тип `int?` по умолчанию хранит не значение 0, а значение `null`.

Этот способ требует дополнительной памяти, потому что тип `int?` занимает на 4-8 байт больше места, чем просто `int`. У него есть и второй недостаток — поведение такой структуры отличается от поведения прочих структур. Это может приводить в замешательство программистов, которые будут обслуживать код.

Но если вы твёрдо уверены в том, что хотите сделать, такой трюк может вам помочь.