# Множество объектов со схожей логикой. Структура или класс?

Tags: c#, wpf, ооп, оптимизация

Вопрос на стыке оптимизации и ООП. У меня есть множество классов или структур(пока что структуры) которые представляют контейнеры для различных команд для IoT устройств. Буду передавать их по сети между сервисами, упаковывать в программируемые UI-пользователем скрипты, ставить в очереди, кто знает что еще придет в голову. Поэтому так заморочился. У команд практически одинаковая логика за исключением количества параметров. Вот пример одной из них:

```
    public struct Set_ct_abx : IDeviceCommand
    {
        public int CommandId { get; }
        int? DeviceId;
        private string JsonPreString;
        private string JsonPostString;
        public Set_ct_abx(int colorTemperature, BulbStateChangingEffect effect, int duration)
        {
            CommandId = CommandIdCounter++;
            DeviceId = null;
            JsonPreString = "{\"id\":";
            JsonPostString = $",\"method\":\"set_ct_abx\",\"params\":[{colorTemperature}, \"{effect}\", {duration}]}}";
        }
        public void SetTargetId(int deviceId)
        {
            DeviceId = deviceId;
        }
        public string GetJson()
        {
            if (DeviceId != null)
                return JsonPreString + DeviceId + JsonPostString;
            else
                throw new Exception("Device ID is not set to the command " + CommandId);
        }
    }
```

Все кроме вот этих строчек повторяется из раза в раз

```
    public struct Set_ct_abx : IDeviceCommand
    {
        public Set_ct_abx(int colorTemperature, BulbStateChangingEffect effect, int duration)
        {
            JsonPreString = "{\"id\":";
            JsonPostString = $",\"method\":\"set_ct_abx\",\"params\":[{colorTemperature}, \"{effect}\", {duration}]}}";
        }
    }
```

Все бы ничего, но таких видов команд более 20-ти для каждого устройства. А если я захочу изменить что-то в общей логике? Это же ад будет. Лучше вынести в общий класс, но структуры не наследуются, C# 7.3 ругается на реализацию в интерфесах. Но в тоже время эти команды будут генерироваться десятками в секунду. Выделение места на куче, сборка мусора.. Реализация классами это удар по производительности, не знаю насколько большой. Но что-то как-то стремно. Что думаете?

Comment: Для передачи обычно используются DTO, то есть объекты, которые кроме данных не содержат в себе вообще нечего. А по поводу структура или класс, честно, я считаю, что вы пытаетесь экономить на спичках, ибо 20 - не так уж и много. Делайте так. как вам удобно в первую очередь, а уж потом думайте об оптимизации (если она нужна конечно будет).

Comment: "Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех зол."

Comment: @EvgeniyZ На счет DTO(я их еще не учил) Да и логику до конца не продумал еще, хотя возможно команды и не придется никуда распихивать. У меня сценарий такой. Классы-плагины отвечают за типы реальных устройств. В них будет логика программирования скриптов для этих устройств. Эти скрипты будут передаваться в хост, в котором они будут подвязываться к событиям возможно Кортана, события windows.. еще чего-то. Еще к хосту будут подвязаны клиенты типа web или еще чего-то. Там по сути нужны будут только ссылки на скрипты.

Comment: Вы сначала определитесь со структурой, поймите как должно работать ваше приложение, напишите его так, как удобно вам и уж потом думайте об оптимизации, если она необходима, сейчас вы себе голову забиваете лишней информацией.У вас сейчас вопрос `Реализация классами это удар по производительности, не знаю насколько большой. Но что-то как-то стремно. Что думаете?` - я вам дал ответ, `в вашем случае, это экономия на спичках`. Про структуры недавно был хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1107335/220553), вот собственно и думайте, критична для вас экономия 8/16 байт или нет.

Comment: О какой производительности может идти речь, если используются интерполяция и конкатенация строк? Это и медленно, и мусора много генерирует.

Comment: EvgeniyZ Спасибо. Возможно и правда рано заморочился. Теперь со спокойной душой буду пилить на классах. На крайняк сведу команды до данных (json+id+priority), либо сделаю команды reusable. P.S. Меня больше беспокоило то что при передачи из одного узла программы в другой объекты не удаляться в конечной точки и будут скапливаться до прихода сборщика мусора. Структуры бы удалялись из стека. Но в принципе, да я понял. Буду решать проблемы по мере их поступления.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov ну, устройствам нуже json, что поделать. Но я понял что видимо не там я потери производительности ищу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что не так с интерполяцией? Да и конкатенация тут скорее всего на тот же String.Concat заменится

Comment: @Grundy - интерполяция заменяется на вызов `string.Format`, в котором поиск места подстановки переменных происходит в рантайме - на это тратится время. И в любом случае в коде автора создаются промежуточные строки - мусор. А он озабочен как раз тем, чтобы избавиться от нагрузки на GC путём замены классов на структуры.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это да, но даже это не кажется пока сильной проблемой :)

Comment: Как я понял, в этом коде главное - создание json, для дальнейшей отправки куда-либо. Вероятно, есть смысл вместо метода `GetJson` сделать метод `WriteToStream`. И писать данные без создания промежуточных строк сразу в стрим (сокет, порт - куда вы их там пишете).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Все отправляется через фасады устросйтв, в которых хранится состояние, логика подключения и переподключения в случае потери связи.Изначально эти команды хранились там в виде методов. Для создания пользовательских скриптов можно было бы конечно использовать делегат с (params[] object) и запихивать методы туда, но мне почему-то кажется что их все равно придется оборачивать во что нибудь. Скрипты ведь нужно будет сериализовывать и сохранять на диск.

Comment: Alexander Petrov еще думаю команды будут идти через класс контроллер шины команд, который будет уведомлять классы подписчики о том что пришла команда с высоким приоритетом, и это событие должно останавливать стрим команд другими классами. Команды должны приходить уже в подготовленном формате json на фасад, где фасад конкретного устройства подставляет id устройства. Команды также будут транслироваться на целые группы устройств.  Короче, думаю все-таки свести сами команды до структуры с метаданными и json и генерировать их вызовом методов отдельного класса.

Comment: Структуры можно положить вне класса, просто в неймспейс, можно с модификатором `internal`. И если у вас стоит вопрос про оптимизацию и при этом не тянуть в проект NuGet пакеты, то переезжайте на .NET Core 3.1, там C# 8.0, и там есть `System.Text.Json`, использование которого добавит вашему коду гибкости и понятности, и избавит от лиших строковых операций. Структура - это облегченный и оптимизированный класс для данных,  и вследствие оптимизации имеет свои ограничения, например структуре нельзя задать параметрический конструктор. Используйте структуры, если они подходят. Если нет - классы.

Comment: @aepot про структуры я знаю. Тут вот в чем прикол. Конечные устройства принимают json, но я не вижу смысла конвертировать их из объектов в плагине. Смотрите, каждый отдельный плагин управляет группой однотипных утройств, отправляя команды json. На вход плагину команды приходят команды от разных UI(web, wpf..) помимо этого будет еще пользовательский программатор в WPF, который будет пушить уже сохраненные на диск команды. Т. е. Все эти "потоки" нужно структурировать. Но они уже в json, с той лишь разницей что не указан ID целевого устр-ва. Так как целью может быть и целая группа устр-в.

Comment: @aepot В итоге размышлений я пришел к тому, что в UI-ях будет генериться json c ключевым словом вместо целевого ID (устр-ва требуют его указания, помимо ip). Если запрос адресован группе в момент отправки его группе устройств будет подставляться id каждого устр-ва в группе. Т. е. все свелось к структуре с json с ключевым словом вместо id, типом команды (одиночная/груповая), именем целевой группы или устройства? Ну и метаданные можно будет добавить при необходимости для распределителя команд.

Comment: @Saint вы решаете задачу "в лоб". Это дешево и эффективно, но только в краткосрочной перспективе. Я бы использовал выше обозначенные технологии. У меня в проектах тоже всякие JSON API, но только там сотни разных методов, а еще они обновляются и меняются каждый месяц, и если бы я использовал ваш подход, я бы уже потерялся и умер в дебрях кода. А так приходится тратить несколько минут на внесение очередных изменений в проект.

Comment: @Saint кстати, вот еще один аспект при работе с всякого рода API, сегодня ночью мы с другим программистом домучали [метод для отправки HTTP POST и GET запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110482). Вдруг вам интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вы решаете задачу "в лоб". Это дешево и эффективно, но только в краткосрочной перспективе. Я бы использовал более подходящие для этого технологии.
- С вашими объемами данных совершенно всё равно, что использовать, классы  или структуры.

Вот простой пример с классом, как можно использовать JSON сериализацию.

Класс с данными у меня получился такой

```csharp
public class DeviceData
{
    [JsonPropertyName(name: "id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName(name: "method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName(name: "params")]
    public List<int> Params { get; set; }
}
```

А вот так я проверил, что всё работает

```cshap
DeviceData deviceData = new DeviceData
{
    Id = 232,
    Method = "set_ct_abx",
    Params = new List<int>
    {
        1000,
        1234,
        -53456
    }
};
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true, // форматирует Json в человекочитаемый вид
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping // человекочитаемый юникод
};
string result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(deviceData, typeof(DeviceData), options);
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Вывод получился такой

```
{
  "id": 232,
  "method": "set_ct_abx",
  "params": [
    1000,
    1234,
    -53456
  ]
}
```

Для работы вышеуказанного кода вам потребуeтся `.NET Core 3.1` (там кстати C# 8.0) и следующие неймспейсы:

```csharp
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
```

А если переписать ваш код, то получится следующее:

```csharp
public struct Set_ct_abx : IDeviceCommand
{
    public int CommandId { get; }
    public DeviceData DeviceData { get; private set; }

    public Set_ct_abx(int colorTemperature, BulbStateChangingEffect effect, int duration)
    {
        CommandId = CommandIdCounter++;
        DeviceData = new DeviceData
        {
            Id = null,
            Method = "set_ct_abx",
            Params = new List<int>
            {
                colorTemperature,
                effect,
                duration
            }
        };
    }
    public void SetTargetId(int deviceId)
    {
        if (DeviceData != null)
            DeviceData.Id = deviceId;
        else
            throw new Exception("Device Data is not set to the command " + CommandId);
    }
    public string GetJson()
    {
        if (DeviceData?.Id != null)
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(DeviceData, typeof(DeviceData));
        else
            throw new Exception("Device ID is not set to the command " + CommandId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Т. е. получается мне нужно конвертировать команду которая пришла из одного из интерфейсов(web, wpf..) в формате Json в структуру, изменить значение id и при отправке непосредственно устройству или группе сконвертировать обратно в Json? Такое дело, что у команд не фиксированное кол-во и тип параметров. Будут получаться разные структуры. Мне придется еще угадывать что именно пришло) Но в принципе логично что программа не должна превращаться в неявный парсер текста json)) И, кстати, я же могу запихнуть json в еще один json? Ну чтобы помимо команды еще метаданные отправлять (#группы и т. д.).

Comment: Кстати, в NET. Framework тоже ведь есть сериализатор json

Comment: @Saint есть, NuGet пакет  Newtonsoft.Json. А вариативное количество параметров - это словарь. Json в Json - это объект в объект?

Comment: Для вариативного набора параметров, если например они одного типа `int` используйте `Dictionary <string, int>`. Если разных типов, то всё сложнее, но тоже с помощью словаря. Но здесь я не смогу всё интересное рассказать, документации и примеров в интернете полно.

Comment: @Saint и советую вам переходить на .NET Core. Это как минимум необходимо чтобы потом перейти на .NET 5.0. Во всяком случае, Microsoft рекомендует именно этот сценарий. Да это может быть нелегко, но я смог 2 небольших WPF проекта портировать за неделю, и не жалею. C# 8.0 - очень приятная штука. :)

Comment: Там может быть вот так `{"id":1,"method":"get_prop","params":["power", "not_exist", "bright"]}`, а может быть вот так `{"id":1,"method":"start_cf","params":[ 4, 2, "1000, 2, 2700, 100, 500, 1,
255, 10, 5000, 7, 0,0, 500, 2, 5000, 1"]`, где каждые четыре числа подряд - отдельный массив. Я уже пробывал гуглить, такие вопросы на StackOverflow уже есть. Почитаю. В принципе, на мой основной вопрос уже ответили несколько раз, так что этот помечу это как ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Переходить на Core я не спешу потому, что я еще пока учусь, и надо хоть что-то доучить. Я немного поигрался с forms, потом узнал про MVVM, перешел на WPF. Теперь еще менять Framework на Core.. Я эту программу по умному дому пишу уже 4 месяца (C# начал учить 8 месяцев назад и еще не доучил, и всего 6 паттернов знаю), а написал только один плагин для освещения и то не до конца, хоста еще тоже нет. А мануал на MSDN по плагин-хост архитектуре, которую я выбрал, он на Framework. Программа для портфолио на GitHub. С такими сроками она мне будет только в минус.

Comment: @Saint Спасибо! WPF на Core практически идентичен. Есть небольшие отличия при сборке приложения, есть возможность собрать все dll в один файл. Я выкинул много лишнего из проектов при переходе. Ну просто потому что оно в Core уже есть и внешние пакеты не нужны.

Comment: @Saint а главная причина, что именно меня толкнуло - это более адекватный дизайнер форм, и задолбали баги в старом. И вот это "C# 7.3 это не поддерживает", когда пытаешься воткнуть из интернета пример в свой код. Кругом уже этот C# 8.0. Если вы пишете 4 месяца, вам хватит часа, чтобы переехать. Конечно, если вы пишете ради дописать и положить на гитхаб (и забыть), а не реально нужную штуковину, которую надо будет потом развивать, то весь этот разговор не имеет смысла. :)

Comment: @Saint и еще .NET Core кросплатформенный. И уже есть даже вменяемые интерфейсные библиотеки на базе OpenGL для Linux. WPF - это конечно только винда, но код, не относящийся к интерфейсам можно без изменений брать и собирать в приложение под Linux или Mac, и MVVM паттерн очень в этом поможет. .NET Framework уже по факту в прошлом, Microsoft так решили, там больше не будет обновлений, только багфиксы и секьюрити-патчи.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106868/discussion-between-saint-and-aepot).