# Есть ли методы ускорения получения данных по api?

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest

Есть код для получения данных по api. Время получения данных 1,5 секунды. Ping 3-15 мс.
Существуют ли другие фреймворки, которые позволяют получать данные быстрее (именно в один поток)? Или может есть какие-то фишечки, которые позволят получать данные быстрее. Например, использование специальных DNS серверов, какие-либо настройки в интернет экспортере или еще чего-нибудь? Я так понимаю, что основное время тут 
затрачивается на отправку пакетов, обработку на сервере и получение данных, могу ли я как-то на это повлиять?

```
private  string CallEndpoint(String Method, String EndPoint, Dictionary<object, object> Params = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request;
        string Url = API_URL + EndPoint;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        if (Params != null && Params.Count > 0)
        {
            string ParamString = string.Join("&", Params.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));

            if (Method == "POST")
            {

                Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
                Request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 20;
                Request.Proxy = null;
                Request.Method = Method;

                var ByteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ParamString);

                Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                Request.ContentLength = ByteData.Length;
                using (var Stream = Request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    Stream.Write(ByteData, 0, ByteData.Length);
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                Url = Url + '?' + ParamString;

                Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

                Request.Method = Method;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

            Request.Method = Method;
        }

        HttpWebResponse Response;
        var ResponseString = "";


        try
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
            sw.Stop();
            ResponseString = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            textBox3.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate ()
            {
                textBox3.AppendText("Время запроса: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "\r\n");
            });
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            ResponseString = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }






        return ResponseString;
    }
```

Попробовал переписать на HttpClient. См. код ниже. Время отклика увеличилось в среднем на 50 мс. Я так понимаю что это обертка над HttpWebRequest. Отсюда и увеличение времени.

Может быть есть еще какие-то идеи?

```
if (method == "POST")
        {

            Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var req in requestParams)
            {
                param.Add(req.Key.ToString(), req.Value.ToString());
            }
            HttpContent ByteData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
            ByteData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, ByteData).Result;
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseContent;
        }
        if (method == "GET")
        {
            if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
            {
                string paramString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
                url += '?' + paramString;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseContent;
        }
```

Мой код, который получился. Убрал даже проверки для улучшения скорости.

```
// HttpClient создается один раз на все время работы приложения.
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private async Task<string> CallEndpointAsync(string method, string endPoint, Dictionary<object, object> requestParams = null)
    {
        string url = API_URL + endPoint;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


        if (method == "POST")
        {
            foreach (var req in requestParams)
            {
                param.Add(req.Key.ToString(), req.Value.ToString());
            }
            HttpContent ByteData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
            ByteData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, ByteData).Result;
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseContent;
        }
        if (method == "GET")
        {
            if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
            {
                string paramString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
                url += '?' + paramString;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseContent;
        }
        else throw new NotImplementedException("Method " + method + " not implemented");
    }
```

Вот такой код получился, только он все равно в вечном ожидании

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private async Task<string> CallEndpointAsync(string method, string endPoint, Dictionary<object, object> requestParams = null)
    {
        string url = API_URL + endPoint;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        if (method == "POST")
        {
            //if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
            //{
            //string ParamString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
            //url += '?' + ParamString;
            //}
            Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var req in requestParams)
            {
                param.Add(req.Key.ToString(), req.Value.ToString());
            }
            HttpContent ByteData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
            ByteData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //Request.ContentLength = ByteData.Length;

            //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, ByteData);
            //string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //return responseContent;

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, ByteData))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // запрос успешен
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    // сюда попадаем, если HTTP 404, 403, 500 и т.д.
                    HttpRequestException httpException = new HttpRequestException((int)response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                    httpException.Data.Add("content-type", response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
                    httpException.Data.Add("body", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    throw httpException;
                }
            }
        }
        if (method == "GET")
        {
            if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
            {
                string paramString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
                url += '?' + paramString;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseContent;
        }
        else throw new NotImplementedException("Method " + method + " not implemented");
    }
```

Comment: Так на что тратится больше всего времени у вас? Что конкретно вам надо оптимизировать?

Comment: Сравнивать время пинга  и время получения данных от сервера некорректно.

Comment: Пинг написал так для справки. Пробовал этот код на фреймворке 4.7.2, на net.core 3.1 и на uwp. На uwp самые быстрые результаты. Хочется ускорить Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

За словами получения данных от сервера скрывается транспорт+обработка не сервере. Как узнать каковы эти значения я не знаю. Но факт того, что в uwp на большом количестве итераций среднее время быстрее на 100 мс, остается фактом.

Comment: Скорее всего тут дело не в uwp, там под капотом все одинаково. Как правило основное время тратится на tcp рукопожатие + у протокола http есть свои особенности и из них вытекает ещё задержка. Как вариант попробуйте изменить протокол с http на чистый tcp, если и этого будет недостаточно то на udp, он самый быстрый.

Comment: udp самый быстрый... ага, конечно. А также не забыть самому менеджить поток, потерю пакетов и прочье. Для начала я бы запустил wireshark и посмотрел, действительно ли рукопожатие занимает сколько время. может обработка сертификата (если это https). А может просто сервер физически не может отдать быстрее.

Comment: Сервер отдать быстрее может, так как другим отдает быстрее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), он переиспользует уже открытые TCP соединения, и в случае повторного обращения к тому же серверу, запрос должен пролететь моментально. Поэтому обязательно сравните время первого запроса и последующих.

В вашем же примере для каждого запроса устанавливается отдельное соединение, которое инициализируется с тяжелым TLS оверхедом. Да даже незашифрованное соединение устанавливается долго. Как вы и сказали, около секунды.

Вот переписал ваш метод под него, правда только для `GET` запроса, и быть может не очень аккуратно, но для теста производительности должно сойти.

```csharp
// HttpClient создается один раз на все время работы приложения.
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<string> CallEndpointAsync(string method, string endPoint, Dictionary<object, object> requestParams = null)
{
    string url = API_URL + endPoint;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    if (method == "GET")
    {
        if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
        {
            string paramString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
            url += '?' + paramString;
        }

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // запрос успешен
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                // сюда попадаем, если HTTP 404, 403, 500 и т.д.
                HttpRequestException httpException = new HttpRequestException((int)response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                httpException.Data.Add("content-type", response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
                httpException.Data.Add("body", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                throw httpException;
            }
        }
    }
    else throw new NotImplementedException("Method " + method + " not implemented");
}
```

Обработка исключений за пределами метода запроса, вот так можно использовать

```csharp
try
{
    string httpResult = CallEndpointAsync("GET", "https://example.com").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    MessageBox.Show(httpResult, "Success"); // данные получены успешно
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    if (ex.Data?.Count > 0 && ex.Data.Contains("content-type") && ex.Data.Contains("body")) // 404, 403, 500?
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Data["content-type"].ToString() + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.Data["body"].ToString(), ex.Message);
    else
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // что-то другое произошло при запросе
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // что-то еще произошло
}
```

---

Чтобы убедиться, что я точно не наврал, вот результат тестов `GET` запроса в JSON API с рабочей нагрузкой, без шифрования, каждый ответ весит ~15кб, время через запятую в миллисекундах, запросы выполняются асинхронно, в **16 потоков**, `.NET Core 3.1`.

Я в Санкт-Петербурге, привожу результаты для 4 идентичных серверов, расположенных в географически разных точках.

Россия

```
403, 167, 229, 290, 151, 136, 161, 138, 203, 208, 201, 205, 2808, 2811, 3002, 3010, 3005, 204, 3015, 208, 207, 193, 188, 192, 184, 189, 196, 193, 3408, 202, 204, 205, 205, 206, 206, 208, 209, 206, 204, 211, 210, 1448, 207, 220, 212, 190, 191, 185, 188, 192, 182, 191, 179, 195, 194, 190, 186, 194, 194, 190, 199, 196, 207, 298, 212, 215, 209, 211, 207, 215, 215, 185, 182, 188, 189, 203, 201, 193, 195, 194, 202, 199, 192, 199, 197, 201, 194, 197, 198, 207, 207, 208, 216, 213, 202, 208, 209, 295, 189, 190, 190, 190, 189, 185, 190, 99, 97, 100, 110, 107, 109, 114, 112, 104, 103, 103, 104, 101, 101, 101, 94, 95, 104, 104, 111, 110, 106, 108, 112, 113, 106, 100, 104, 102, 105, 105, 102, 109, 105, 105, 105, 109, 108, 112, 107, 106, 190, 188, 193, 104, 202, 200, 206, 187, 110, 111, 109, 110, 198, 192, 103, 185, 105, 101, 186, 95, 100, 102, 97, 175, 180, 101, 192, 99, 99, 170, 100, 103, 102, 98, 175, 96, 176, 187, 102, 190, 101, 112, 101, 179, 171, 175, 101, 101, 103, 103, 175, 96, 182, 97, 103, 101, 180, 102, 179, 97, 183, 114, 113, 220, 176, 100, 113, 106, 104, 111, 189, 191, 108, 184, 110, 109, 107, 109, 195, 106, 112, 197, 195, 112, 112, 113, 104, 193, 103, 194, 103, 103, 108, 102, 104, 180, 188, 107, 107, 107, 105, 101, 115, 114, 111, 113, 119, 108, 196, 189, 102, 101, 196, 103, 120, 119, 107, 108, 104, 111, 117, 103, 196, 113, 199, 117, 106, 107, 106, 144, 144, 141, 137, 135, 216, 131, 138, 134, 149, 146, 147, 151, 140, 224, 113, 106, 108, 110, 98, 107, 105, 197, 318, 106, 177, 178, 100, 100, 101, 98, 182
total time: 8337
total queries: 307
```

Германия

```
112, 143, 197, 503, 556, 547, 523, 552, 529, 555, 529, 663, 628, 656, 227, 671, 653, 661, 137, 648, 204, 202, 207, 203, 202, 205, 90, 87, 205, 87, 92, 95, 94, 91, 98, 111, 82, 84, 91, 99, 98, 108, 98, 95, 110, 99, 98, 93, 92, 104, 109, 113, 179, 149, 161, 153, 146, 175, 155, 150, 145, 144, 209, 188, 194, 215, 192, 196, 81, 82, 89, 209, 205, 200, 206, 141, 201, 144, 147, 202, 139, 205, 207, 204, 209, 208, 205, 87, 83, 88, 86, 209, 203, 212, 217, 149, 208, 146, 146, 148, 149, 205, 216, 201, 199, 210, 206, 82, 81, 194, 201, 209, 144, 196, 146, 153, 190, 152, 201, 199, 194, 221, 206, 196, 198, 85, 211, 199, 207, 199, 192, 201, 202, 197, 199, 154, 150, 199, 195, 193, 182, 199, 79, 85, 82, 93, 91, 100, 93, 83, 149, 86, 165, 157, 83, 89, 165, 166, 163, 162, 165, 91, 83, 257, 250, 186, 183, 176, 146, 146, 148, 206, 86, 87, 85, 205, 205, 209, 205, 206, 140, 149, 201, 194, 80, 98, 92, 89, 91, 202, 203, 145, 146, 186, 215, 203, 202, 92, 197, 88, 89, 95, 132, 136, 191, 195, 202, 197, 211, 90, 92, 211, 218, 134, 140, 132, 192, 199, 204, 198, 207, 201, 88, 86, 90, 82, 87, 90, 84, 96, 105, 95, 95, 99, 184, 180, 165, 167, 161, 166, 171, 165, 169, 82, 83, 209, 211, 199, 205, 211, 212, 207, 161, 202, 79, 206, 203, 199, 196, 151, 196, 200, 201, 153, 87, 84, 86, 203, 207, 196, 198, 201, 204, 157, 264, 267, 268, 273, 276, 213, 281, 92, 216, 276, 206, 211, 210, 203, 206, 200, 155, 154, 200, 211, 200, 196, 209, 203, 197, 88, 102, 89, 81, 89, 86, 88, 213
total time: 4496
total queries: 307
```

США

```
238, 339, 235, 233, 236, 281, 232, 233, 239, 232, 287, 240, 3271, 3257, 3260, 3270, 3274, 232, 232, 233, 233, 234, 232, 232, 232, 235, 233, 236, 258, 240, 3949, 3954, 231, 230, 232, 231, 232, 232, 232, 230, 234, 237, 236, 237, 233, 233, 232, 234, 230, 230, 236, 234, 234, 234, 230, 233, 228, 230, 229, 233, 233, 236, 230, 232, 233, 232, 231, 231, 238, 234, 234, 234, 229, 235, 229, 235, 233, 239, 232, 235, 230, 231, 230, 232, 234, 237, 232, 232, 233, 234, 232, 232, 918, 908, 923, 915, 902, 921, 942, 934, 234, 235, 239, 234, 242, 231, 235, 233, 231, 239, 237, 236, 235, 239, 238, 238, 240, 237, 242, 237, 242, 245, 244, 238, 237, 233, 237, 234, 235, 231, 235, 236, 234, 234, 232, 234, 235, 235, 235, 234, 236, 235, 238, 235, 235, 236, 233, 233, 452, 236, 453, 237, 460, 239, 237, 449, 451, 461, 459, 460, 234, 451, 231, 459, 459, 236, 231, 235, 239, 236, 237, 236, 235, 235, 237, 242, 329, 319, 311, 313, 307, 319, 323, 310, 309, 319, 314, 323, 327, 324, 332, 331, 241, 239, 237, 239, 236, 241, 249, 239, 238, 250, 249, 230, 232, 236, 237, 247, 235, 240, 340, 349, 349, 347, 345, 330, 343, 343, 338, 232, 234, 357, 361, 373, 250, 242, 383, 384, 241, 346, 347, 342, 351, 313, 365, 359, 318, 345, 363, 342, 349, 356, 352, 349, 246, 239, 360, 252, 244, 244, 246, 241, 249, 241, 246, 250, 252, 256, 259, 253, 255, 255, 252, 260, 259, 255, 258, 264, 279, 338, 331, 323, 318, 317, 316, 312, 302, 297, 323, 310, 289, 302, 310, 292, 319, 245, 248, 250, 243, 256, 252, 246, 245, 250, 244, 246, 233, 247, 236, 243, 246, 236, 235, 233, 241, 243, 242
total time: 9484
total queries: 307
```

Сингапур

```
317, 246, 245, 255, 247, 251, 245, 248, 247, 390, 362, 3143, 3140, 3152, 3163, 3153, 3140, 3281, 239, 243, 363, 362, 361, 364, 357, 243, 238, 357, 3751, 244, 245, 260, 259, 367, 352, 314, 353, 354, 348, 356, 343, 344, 246, 249, 248, 237, 237, 242, 239, 237, 239, 256, 262, 263, 238, 241, 243, 239, 239, 241, 245, 357, 240, 241, 241, 244, 238, 242, 470, 350, 287, 983, 983, 271, 990, 285, 970, 971, 982, 966, 274, 292, 280, 804, 243, 253, 260, 258, 256, 255, 255, 249, 233, 237, 238, 246, 240, 237, 238, 245, 667, 643, 656, 654, 659, 646, 646, 237, 240, 239, 785, 351, 361, 356, 355, 361, 241, 244, 242, 248, 244, 249, 245, 247, 462, 462, 335, 330, 287, 290, 285, 348, 325, 323, 281, 297, 251, 329, 279, 294, 236, 242, 239, 242, 248, 242, 245, 246, 254, 239, 471, 242, 244, 479, 245, 478, 244, 484, 489, 479, 631, 356, 456, 456, 458, 238, 242, 243, 361, 362, 366, 362, 364, 365, 366, 371, 247, 247, 235, 240, 239, 234, 239, 472, 344, 341, 346, 343, 339, 341, 335, 334, 294, 315, 306, 351, 303, 277, 332, 244, 248, 249, 251, 269, 271, 256, 254, 253, 257, 381, 382, 374, 404, 384, 383, 240, 244, 241, 244, 364, 363, 361, 359, 359, 363, 250, 248, 248, 252, 259, 247, 242, 247, 366, 364, 244, 251, 250, 250, 249, 252, 242, 242, 239, 239, 240, 241, 236, 357, 246, 250, 239, 239, 248, 243, 245, 243, 243, 246, 246, 240, 240, 240, 238, 242, 238, 238, 236, 237, 244, 242, 248, 252, 251, 244, 249, 246, 245, 252, 240, 241, 239, 239, 240, 240, 243, 241, 238, 243, 242, 248, 243, 243, 240, 243, 242, 244, 242, 244, 238, 243, 241, 241, 252, 244, 246, 243
total time: 9546
total queries: 307
```

Все запросы уникальные (кеширование исключено). Можно увидеть некторые запросы, время выполнения в которых ощутимо выше, чем у остальных, в них и создается новое соединение, когда уже открытых не хватает. Общий объем полученных данных 3,5 МБ на каждые 307 запросов.

---

Вот, дописал ваш метод под C# 8.0, .NET Core

```csharp
private async Task<string> CallEndpointAsync(string method, string endPoint, Dictionary<object, object> requestParams = null)
{
    string url = API_URL + endPoint;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    if (method == "POST")
    {
        foreach (var req in requestParams)
        {
            param.Add(req.Key.ToString(), req.Value.ToString());
        }
        using HttpContent ByteData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
        ByteData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, ByteData).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    if (method == "GET")
    {
        if (requestParams?.Count > 0)
        {
            string paramString = string.Join("&", requestParams.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}"));
            url += '?' + paramString;
        }

        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Method " + method + " not implemented");
}
```

Comment: Код переписал, но время только увеличилось в среднем на 50 мс. Видимо, HttpClient это обертка для HttpWebRequest

Comment: @arc_pd Покажите код, отредактируйте вопрос, у меня после переписывания стало в разы лучше. Но у меня .Net Core 3.1. Интересно увидеть код, где вы вызываете метод.

Comment: @arc_pd по поводу обертки, там [не всё так просто](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @arc_pd добавил детальные результаты тестов в ответ. Самый быстрый запрос - 79мс, за это время успевает улететь запрос и вернуться 15 килобайт ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за проделанное исследование. Но у меня не получается быстрее, не могу сказать с чем связано.

Comment: @arc_pd Убедитесь, что `HttpClient` создается не при каждом запросе, а один раз на всё время работы приложения. Это важно. Покажите код работы с http полностью.

Comment: Обновил первый пост.

Comment: @arc_upd вместо `.Result` используйте `await` как в моем ответе, везде. А что за класс, где этот метод находится, когда и где он создается?

Comment: Как только ставлю await, данные вообще не получаю и программа в вечном ожидании.

Comment: @arc_pd не туда значит ставите, после равно надо.

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, ByteData);
string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: @arc_upd во, перед `HttpResponseMessage` добавьте `using` обязательно, потому что он `IDispisable`. У вас же .NET Core?

Comment: @arc_upd Ща за комп сяду, перепишу ваш код

Comment: Есть проект и на core, сейчас тестирую на фреймворке 4.7.2. Сейчас попробую, отпишусь

Comment: @arc_upd есть разница C# 8.0 и C# 7.3, вам под Core или Framework надо?

Comment: Мне не важно где, мне важна скорость)

Comment: @arc_pd готово, добавил в ответ. Возможно проблема как раз была в отсутствии `using`, и `HttpResponseMessage` не освобождал сокет. Проверяйте. :)

Comment: Попробовал Ваш код, но все так же, в net core, постоянное ожидание, без вызова каких либо ошибок

Comment: @arc_pd Покажите, как вы вызываете `CallEndpointAsync`. GET или POST?

Comment: var Params = InitializeDictionary();
            Params.Add("api_key", API_KEY);
            Params.Add("time", GetTimestamp());
            Params.Add("sign", GetSign(Params));

            var Response = CallEndpointAsync("POST", "/v1/account", Params);

Comment: Неправильно вызываете, `var Response = CallEndpointAsync("POST", "/v1/account", Params).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` надо.

Comment: @arc_pd обновил код, добавил еще один `using` для `HttpContent`, он тоже `IDisposable`.

Comment: Попробовал и getawaiter поставил, и с еще одним using. Все равно происходит зависание. Вот видео yadi[dot]sk/i/xeza7Cpp6fYLRg

Comment: @arc_pd обновил код, добавил `ConfigureAwait(false)`, слышал что при восстановлении контекста можно нарваться на дедлок, если его не указать. Ох уж эта асинхронность. Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, да. Так все работает. Тесты правда сделаю уже завтра, но на первый взгляд действительно выигрыш в скорости есть!